# XAMPP has stopped working on the router (local network)

Tags: xampp, localhost

How do I fix this problem. Xampp was working for me on the router, and I could access it from other devices on the router from this link 192.168.0.5 . Now it has stopped working on these devices.

I tried changing the port and tried more than one solution, but it didn't work for me, even though it was working well.

Comment: We can't possibly help you without any relevant technical info, or even a basic error message report. See [ask]

Comment: There is no error message, unfortunately, only what appears is that . this page can't be reached

Comment: Well that's an error message, isn't it?? Anyway, it suggests that possibly Apache is not listening on that port. So check the Apache settings first of all. Or it could be a firewall issue, so also check your firewall rules (both inbound on the server, and outbound on the machine you're calling it from). Lastly check the general networking - can you reach 192.168.0.5 via any other services (e.g. shared folders, or ping, or simple telnet, or whatever other service it might expose)? If not, then the machine might be generally inaccessible on the network, or have been allocated a new IP address.

Comment: ok, I'll check those things out. Thank you for your help